# Хочу создать команду размьют (unmute time-out)

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Хочу создать команду именно команду потому что постоянно вижу на ютубе только слеш команды размьют так же чтобы она работала так как показано снизу плюсом к этому тут должны быть:

1. проверка на наличие разрешения кика и должно выдавать ошибку по типу

   `❌ У вас недостаточно прав на размьют!`
2. Если не указать участника и должно выдавать ошибку по типу

   `❌ Вы не указали кому нужно снять мьют.`
3. если есть мьют размутить и должно выдавать сообщение

   `✅ участник <@username> был размьючен по причине: <причина>.`

   если без причины то так

   `✅ участник <@username> был размьючен.`
4. если мьюта нету у участника должно выдавать ошибку

   `❌ <@username> не имеет мьют.`

Помогите пожалуйста я уже замучался искать. Заранее большое спасибо

1. пример

   ```
   >размьют <@username>
   ```
2. пример

   ```
   >размьют <@username> <причина>
   ```

Comment: У вас же был код...

Comment: Ну так сделайте по аналогии, только выдавайте противоположную роль. Конкретно этот вопрос без кода и конкретной проблемы **на этом сайте** не имеет смысла. За вас здесь код не напишут, поэтому, если хотите получить ответ — сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на конкретной проблеме. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка Нее тот был мьют (который блокировал отпарвку сообщений пользователя) а тут наоборот размьют (команда должна снимать мьют у челика у которого уже есть мьют)

Comment: @denisnumb если честно я могу сделать ошибки и тд но у меня не получается найти основу а именно как самого челика размьютить который в мьюте (тайм-ауте

Comment: @Lordeyser я вам этим и помог, а готовый код за вас здесь не пишут...

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка я имею ввиду нужно не весь код а часть кода которую я не могу написать в данный момент у меня возникаю сложности с проверкой то есть что написать в if чтобы человека размьютить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы "разтаймаутить" участника, используйте команду `await member.timeout(duration=None)` в [disnake](/questions/tagged/disnake) и [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py).

Comment: Как мне добавить это с проверкой? напишите более подробно пожайлуста

Comment: @Lordeyser лень... потом добавлю

Comment: @Lordeyser тут не сайт написания кодов, а помощь

Comment: @Четкая Четырка я кароче откапал исходники мьюта и все получилось большое спасибо! Только возникает другая проблема с причиной всегда пишет почему-то None. Я создам новый пост чтобы вы поняли про что я говорю.